# Dell N7110 i7 overheats and doesn't boot when anything is plugged into the USB3 port

Tags: usb, dell, fan, overheating, noise

When i plug in any devices (mouse, keyboard) into usb 3.0 system dell n7110 overheats and fan goes crazy with terrible noise.

So i'm using 1 usb 2.0 slot now with a usb hub. It doesn't solve the problem completely but system stays at a low fan rate for a longer time.

I've tried to lower CPU frequency, but in my case (DELL INSPIRON N7110 i7 on Linux 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) CPU was pretty cool (51 C) and still the same horrible fan noise.

Looks like there is no such problems with ubuntu 10.04 (but there're some other problems).

Ubuntu even doesn't boot if anything is plugged into usb 3.0

Comment: Have you upgraded to the latest kernel and seen if it has resolved the issue? I'm not certain about the USB 3.0 issue not allowing Ubuntu to boot - I suspect it may be related to a bios setting to enable booting from USB 3.0.

Comment: I have the exact same computer and I have exact same problem -- but I use Ubuntu 12.04. I've try Mint and Dabian and same.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: This should be filed as a bug. I'd start by running `ubuntu-bug linux` and that should upload handy information for developers to look at at the same time. Be sure to include as much hardware information as you can.